# Convención de nombres en PHP

Tags: php

Sabiendo que la convención de nombres es un conjunto de normas y reglas para la escritura de nombres, código fuente, identificadores y comentarios dentro de la programación, que facilitan y hacen más comprensible su lectura...

¿Cuáles son las convenciones de nombres más usadas en PHP?

**Nota:** Esta es una auto-respuesta, que tiene como objetivo guardar un punto de referencia a la hora de elegir una convención de nombres en el lenguaje PHP.

Comment: Ofrezco una recompensa para agradecer el esfuerzo y destacar la utilidad de estas preguntas-respuestas. ¡La comunidad debe estar contenta de contar con tal nivel de publicaciones!

Comment: @fedorqui parecería que tu recompensa ha desatado la ira de algunos trolls... ya llevo al menos 4 ó 5 preguntas/respuestas votadas en contra desde entonces. Entre ellas la presente,  [y también esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/105921/29967), que acabo de mejorar considerablemente. De todos modos agradezco la generosidad de tu gesto. Saludos.

Comment: Caramba, ¡qué rabia me da! Créeme que me entristece. Estuve buceando en muchas de tus preguntas y respuestas para ver en cuál poner la recompensa, pues hay muchas buenas y me parece que se les da poca difusión. Entiendo que pueda haber habido discusiones pasadas que hayan creado enemistades, pero votar por algo distinto al contenido es perjudicial para todos. Sugiero reportarlo para que los moderadores puedan investigar y actuar en consecuencia.

Comment: @A.Cedano algunos usuarios de la comunidad piensan que son buenas aportaciones pero podrían ser wiki de comunidad, que piensas?

Comment: @Jorgesys mi experiencia con las Wiki de comunidad no ha sido muy buena. He lanzado algunas... pero creo que es un asunto que no queda claro para algunos de los usuarios. En varias ocasiones ha ocurrido que al responder con una Wiki de comunidad otros usuarios no editan la respuesta, sino que responden con otra respuesta adicional. Esa forma de proceder indica que, o no se comprende el sentido de las Wiki o soy yo el que está confundido al respecto. Esto sería algo para discutirlo en Meta, pero [aquí dejo un ejemplo de lo que digo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/111912/29967).

Comment: @Jorgesys La respuesta a la presente pregunta sí podría ser perfectamente Wiki de comunidad, ya que se podrían aportar nuevas convenciones de nombre que no aparezcan aquí... pero no sé si la recompensa motive a que otros usuarios aporten más respuestas en lugar de tratar de mejorar lo que ya existe.

Comment: Se ha debatido muchas veces en Meta y pensaba que había cierto consenso, @Jorgesys . Se pondria en modo wiki de comunidad si se pretende crear una publicación colaborativa en la que cada cual vaya mejorando la información existente. Si tienes una respuesta que consideras exhaustiva, no considero que sea necesario marcarla como tal. En todo caso, siempre son bienvenidas las mejoras puntuales. Si tu pretensión sí es llamar a la acción, siempre puedes poner un pequeño título indicándolo para los despistados.

Comment: Cuando yo llegué a este sitio (había participado sólo en la versión gringa) no entendía la idea de hacer preguntas y autoresponderlas. En buenas cuentas no son realmente preguntas, son más bien como un hilo de discusión y reflexión. Esos votos negativos han de ser porque alguien dijo: "este señor se autoresponde para ganar más puntaje"

Comment: La pregunta está bien, quizás un poco genérica (realmente no es PHP y se podría aplicar a cualquier lenguaje). Pero, a título personal, quitaría una cosa: la nota al final sobre esto siendo una auto-respuesta me sobra. Parece que es como decir "no voy a aceptar respuestas de otros usuarios" y eso va en contra del espíritu del sitio.

Comment: La idea de la nota no era @AlvaroMontoro. Puse la nota debido a alguna controversia con alguna auto-respuesta en la que alguno se quejaba de por qué preguntaba si iba a responder yo mismo. Lo de las preguntas autorespondidas sigue siendo un punto delicado ya que a algunas les gustan, a otros les disgustan. La nota iba en ese sentido. En algún caso yo he marcado como buena la respuesta de otro, considerando que era mejor. Lo mismo aquí, si hubiere una respuesta mejor, haría lo mismo.

Comment: @fedorqui al menos en Chile "en buenas cuentas" significa "en el fondo" o "en otras palabras"

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Con respecto a la convención de nombres hay que tomar en cuenta que muchas convenciones de nombre hacen uso de las mayúsculas y minúsculas en sus identificadores. Ese uso varía según el tipo de elemento que se quiera identificar.

Entre ellas tenemos:

#### 1. `PascalCase`

La primera letra del identificador y la primera letra de las siguientes palabras concatenadas están en mayúsculas. El estilo de mayúsculas y minúsculas Pascal se puede utilizar en identificadores de tres o más caracteres, por ejemplo:
`MiClase`

#### 2. `camelCase`

La primera letra del identificador está en minúscula y la primera letra de las siguientes palabras concatenadas en mayúscula, por ejemplo:
`unaPropiedad`

#### 3. `ALL_CAPS`

Todas las letras del identificador se encuentran en mayúsculas y las palabras se separan por un guión bajo `_`. Ejemplo
`UNA_CONSTANTE`

#### 4. `small_caps`

Todas las letras del identificador se encuentran en minúsculas y las palabras separadas por `_`. Ejemplo:
`una_funcion`

#### 5. `Proper_Case`

Como CamelCase, pero cada inicio de palabra separado por un `_`. Se usa muy poco.

---

Esta tabla muestra las principales convenciones de nombres para los diferentes elementos del programa en PHP.

La misma fue posteada originalmente [aquí](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/149321).:

```
╔══════════════════╦═════════════╦════════════╦══════════════╦════════════╦════════════╗
║ Proyecto PHP     ║ Clases      ║ Métodos    ║ Propiedades  ║ Funciones  ║ Variables  ║
╠══════════════════╬═════════════╬════════════╬══════════════╬════════════╬════════════╣
║ Akelos           ║ PascalCase  ║ camelCase  ║ camelCase    ║ lower_case ║ lower_case ║
║ CakePHP          ║ PascalCase  ║ camelCase  ║ camelCase    ║ camelCase  ║ camelCase  ║
║ CodeIgniter      ║ Proper_Case ║ lower_case ║ lower_case   ║ lower_case ║ lower_case ║
║ Concrete5 CMS    ║ PascalCase  ║ camelCase  ║ camelCase    ║ lower_case ║ lower_case ║
║ Doctrine ORM     ║ PascalCase  ║ camelCase  ║ camelCase    ║ camelCase  ║ camelCase  ║
║ Drupal CMS       ║ PascalCase  ║ camelCase  ║ camelCase    ║ lower_case ║ lower_case ║
║ Joomla CMS       ║ PascalCase  ║ camelCase  ║ camelCase    ║ camelCase  ║ camelCase  ║
║ modx CMS         ║ PascalCase  ║ camelCase  ║ camelCase    ║ camelCase  ║ lower_case ║
║ Pear             ║ PascalCase  ║ camelCase  ║ camelCase    ║ ---------- ║ ---------- ║
║ Prado            ║ PascalCase  ║ camelCase  ║ Pascal/camel ║ ---------- ║ lower_case ║
║ SimplePie RSS    ║ PascalCase  ║ lower_case ║ lower_case   ║ lower_case ║ lower_case ║
║ Symfony          ║ PascalCase  ║ camelCase  ║ camelCase    ║ camelCase  ║ camelCase  ║
║ Laravel          ║ PascalCase  ║ camelCase  ║ camelCase    ║ camelCase  ║ camelCase  ║
║ Yii 2            ║ PascalCase  ║ camelCase  ║ camelCase    ║ camelCase  ║ camelCase  ║
║ Phalcon          ║ PascalCase  ║ camelCase  ║ camelCase    ║ camelCase  ║ camelCase  ║
║ Slim Framework   ║ PascalCase  ║ camelCase  ║ camelCase    ║ camelCase  ║ camelCase  ║
║ FuelPHP          ║ PascalCase  ║ camelCase  ║ camelCase    ║ camelCase  ║ camelCase  ║
║ PHPPixie         ║ PascalCase  ║ camelCase  ║ camelCase    ║ camelCase  ║ camelCase  ║
║ Laminas Project  ║ PascalCase  ║ camelCase  ║ camelCase    ║ camelCase  ║ camelCase  ║
║ Fat-Free         ║ PascalCase  ║ camelCase  ║ camelCase    ║ camelCase  ║ camelCase  ║
║ Lumen            ║ PascalCase  ║ camelCase  ║ camelCase    ║ camelCase  ║ camelCase  ║
║ Flight           ║ PascalCase  ║ camelCase  ║ camelCase    ║ camelCase  ║ camelCase  ║
╚══════════════════╩═════════════╩════════════╩══════════════╩════════════╩════════════╝
```

Comment: deberías agregar que pasa con los namespace propiamente y que pasa con los nombres de archivos y directorios intermediarios...