# Pasar un valor a una variable desde una clase con su función php

Tags: php

Tengo esto en otro archivo:

```
<?php
class main_class {
    public function name_main(){
         return 'NOMBRE PRINCIpal';
    }
}
```

y mi index:

```
require('core/models/class/main_class.php');
//END CLASS

$NAME=new main_class();
$NAME->name_main();
```

me da el error:
Object of class main_class could not be converted to string

Quiero colocarlo en el title

```
<title><?php echo $NAME;?> | Inicio</title>
```

y me causan errores, que puedo hacer?

Comment: intenta con: `echo $NAME->name_main();`

Comment: pero cuando lo pongo en el title,  me da ese error

Comment: convert a string

Comment: Intenta asignarlo a una variable.

Comment: ya lo hice y me sigue saliendo lo mismo

Comment: Deberias agregar el codigo del title

Comment: intensar parsearlo `json_encode($NAME);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### El problema

`$NAME` es la instancia de la clase que creaste aquí:

```
$NAME=new main_class();
```

Por eso al escribir: <s>`<title><?php echo $NAME;?> | Inicio</title>`</s> te sale el error:

> Object of class main_class could not be converted to string

Porque estás haciendo `echo` de la instancia de la clase sin más.

---

### La solución

Lo correcto sería escribir:

```
<title><?php echo $NAME->name_main();?> | Inicio</title>
```

---

### Yendo más lejos...

Cuando se crea una instancia de una clase, se usa el siguiente esquema para invocar sus métodos:

```
nombre de la instancia -> método()
$objMain               -> name_main()
```

Generalmente, con los métodos que devuelven datos (los que finalizan con `return`), se suele almacenar el resultado del método en una variable, aunque también se puede usar directamente. El uso de variables da más claridad al código y no tienes que volver a llamar a ese método en caso de necesitar su resultado varias veces si el estado de esa propiedad no cambia.

Por ejemplo:

```
/*Se crea la instancia de la clase*/
$objMain=new main_class();

/*Se asigna a la variable $theName el valor que devuelve el método*/
$theName=$objMain->name_main();

/*Se usa la variable*/
echo $theName;
```

***Salida:***

```
NOMBRE PRINCIpal
```

En este caso, y para evitar la *horrible* mezcla de código PHP/HTML, yo lo haría así, en caso de necesitar el valor del método sólo una vez:

```
echo "<title>".$objMain->name_main()." | Inicio</title>";
```

O bien así, si necesitarás el título completo para más adelante:

```
$theTitle="<title>".$objMain->name_main()." | Inicio</title>";
echo $theTitle;
```

***Salida:***

En ambos casos el resultado es el mismo...

```
<title>NOMBRE PRINCIpal | Inicio</title>
```

En cambio, si el valor que devuelve el método ha de ser usado más adelante en el código:

```
$theName=$objMain->name_main();
echo "<title>$theName | Inicio</title>";
```

***Salida:***

```
<title>NOMBRE PRINCIpal | Inicio</title>
```

Y... cuando necesites más adelante usar el valor del método, echas mano de la variable `$theName` ya creada sin necesidad de volver a llamar al método.

```
echo $theName;  //en la(s) otra(s) parte(s) donde la necesitaba
```

---

**NOTA SOBRE LA CONVENCIÓN DE NOMBRES:**

Si observas, yo he llamado a la instancia de la clase `$objMain` en los ejemplos que he puesto, tratando así de usar una convención de nombres adecuada. Al ver la variable, puedo saber que es un `obj`eto  y que me creará una instancia de la clase `main`.  Si bien el código funciona de cualquiera de las dos maneras, conviene implementar una convención de nombres que te ayude a entender/mantener el código, sobre todo cuando el programa crece o cuando varios programadores trabajan sobre el mismo proyecto.

Por lo general, en la convención de nombres de la mayoría de lenguajes de programación, las mayúsculas se usan para las constantes, jamás para variables simples o para nombres de objetos.

Para más detalles sobre esto puedes leer: [Convención de nombres en PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/78513/29967)

Answer (score 1):

El `echo` donde imprimes el `<title>` esta intentando imprimir $NAME, que no es un `string`, sino una instancia de una clase. Para que te imprima la `string`, debes imprimir la función en la instancia del objeto, ya que esta es la que te retorna el `string`;

```
<title><?php echo $NAME->name_main(); ?> | Inicio</title>
```

Comment: me sgue dando error