# Notice: Undefined property PHP en class heredadas

Tags: php, php5

Estoy estudiando PHP, y me surge un problema (Notice: Undefined property) cuando hago el ejercicio de HERENCIAS de las class.

Más concretamente me dice:

> "Notice: Undefined property: dobleheredada::$muninterno in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto_php_seas\418-herencias.php on line 25".

Si alguen puede ayudarme estaría superagradecida, ya que mis profes están de vacas.

Pongo el código en PHP y luego el resultado:

**************Código PHP:*************

```
    <?php
    class doble {

      var $mult=2;
      public $numinterno;



      public function multxnum() {
        return $this->mult*$this->numinterno;
      }

      public function divxnum () {

        return $this->numinterno/$this->mult;
      }

    }


    class dobleheredada extends doble {


      public function triple() {
        return ($this->multxnum()*$this->muninterno);
      }
    }

    $miobjeto= new doble();
    $miobjeto->numinterno=3;
    $eldoble=$miobjeto->multxnum();

    echo "El valor doble del parámetro es: $eldoble";
    echo "<br>";

    $lamitad=$miobjeto->divxnum();
    echo "El valor mitad del parámetro es: $lamitad";

    $objeto3=new dobleheredada();
    $objeto3->numinterno=3;
    $eltriple=$objeto3->triple();

    echo "<br>";
    echo "El doble del cuadrado del parámetro es: ".$objeto3->triple();
    echo "El doble del cuadrado del parámetro es: $eltriple";

    ?>
```

*************Resultado del Script:**********

> El valor doble del parámetro es: 6
>
> El valor mitad del parámetro es: 1.5
>
> Notice: Undefined property: dobleheredada::$muninterno in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto_php_seas\418-herencias.php on line 25
>
> Notice: Undefined property: dobleheredada::$muninterno in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto_php_seas\418-herencias.php on line 25  El
>   doble del cuadrado del parámetro es: 0El doble del cuadrado del
>   parámetro es: 0"

Comment: Tienes un typo, deberia ser `numinterno` en lugar de `muninterno`

Comment: @alanfcm muchísimas gracias! no sé porque eclipse, no me lo chivó. Tendrías alguna sugerencia para que me "chiven" esta clase de errores?

Comment: El error mismo te lo dice. solo tienes que prestar atencion y leer cuidadosamente el retorno que te proporciona PHP.

Comment: Considera aplicar una [Convención de nombres](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/78513/29967) adecuada para los nombres de variables, clases, métodos/funciones, etc, te ayudará a evitar confusiones como estas y a no desconcertarte ante el análisis/comprensión de un programa con una cierta extensión en cuanto al código.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por vuestras aportaciones!

Answer (score 0):

En tu clase dobleheredada tienes:

```
public function triple() {
        return ($this->multxnum()*$this->muninterno);
      }
```

Debe ser:

```
public function triple() {
    return ($this->multxnum()*$this->numinterno);
  }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! De verdad, esto de empezar a programar es un rollo hasta que te haces con estas cosas!

Comment: De nada!, solo observa bien el mensaje que te da, generalmente ahí te explica el error detalladamente ;)