# Obtener valor de propiedad static desde archivo php

Tags: php

Me estreno en esta comunidad con la siguiente duda que no termino de ver.

Si yo creo una clase en la que establezco unas propiedades y métodos de tipo static, ¿como puedo recuperar luego el valor de esas propiedades desde otro fichero?

Ejemplo:

```
final class website {

    public static $valor;

    private function __construct() {

    }

    public static function setValor($x) {
        self::$valor= $x;        
    }

    public static function getValor() {
        return self::$valor;
    }
}
```

Si intento hacer esto desde otro archivo .php el resultado que obtengo es null.

```
website::getValor();
```

¿Alguién me puede dar una idea?

Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### El por qué del error

Te devuelve `NULL` porque al hacer:

```
website::getValor();
```

En ese momento el miembro `$valor` de la clase no tiene datos. De hecho, por lo general una propiedad declarada como `static` debería ser declarada con algún valor por defecto (más adelante veremos por qué).

Si haces esto por ejemplo:

```
website::setValor(1);
```

Y luego:

```
echo website::getValor();
```

Verás en pantalla un `1`, porque la propiedad de la clase ha adquirido un valor que antes no tenía.

O si la declaras con un valor por defecto, verás dicho valor al invocarla:

```
public static $valor=0;
```

### ¿Para qué sirve una propiedad o miembro `static`? ¿Cuándo debo declarar `static`?

Hay que ser cuidadosos a la hora de declarar un miembro `static` en una clase.

De entrada hay que decir que el uso de miembros estáticos (como también la declaración de variables globales), es considerado una **mala práctica**. Aunque esto no quiero decir que hay que ver al demonio cuando vemos una estática. Hay casos en que podrían ser convenientes y lo veremos con algunos ejemplos prácticos.

La particularidad de las propiedades declaradas `static` en una clase, es que **las mismas pertenecen a la clase en sí, y no la instancia de la clase**. Eso quiere decir que podemos hacer uso de ellas sin necesidad de crear una nueva instancia de esa clase. Por eso podemos acceder tan solo haciendo: `Clase::$miembroEstatico;`

La pregunta entonces es: ¿cuándo se justifica esto? O sea, ¿en qué casos sería mejor tener una propiedad de la clase a la que pueda acceder sin necesidad de instanciar esa clase?

Un caso muy común es cuando necesitamos un contandor en la clase para lo que sea. Esa propiedad se puede declarar como `static`.

Generalmente esas propiedades estáticas existen en clases utilitarias de las cuales echamos mano en muchas partes del programa.

Consideremos una clase `Utils` donde por cualquier motivo necesitamos, entre otras cosas, mantener un contador:

```
class Utils 
{
  static public $contador = 0;

  static public function addValue($value)
  {
    self::$contador+= $value;
  }
}
```

Si en varias partes del programa nosotros necesitamos modificar/obtener dicho contador, se justifica en esa clase tanto una propiedad como un miembro `static` para  manejar esa situación.

Imaginemos varias partes del programa:

```
/*Necesitamos valor inicial del contador*/
echo Utils::$contador.PHP_EOL;

/*Necesitamos agregar 1*/
Utils::addValue(1);
echo Utils::$contador.PHP_EOL;

/*Necesitamos agregar 5*/
Utils::addValue(5);
echo Utils::$contador.PHP_EOL;

/*Necesitamos agregar 9*/
Utils::addValue(9);
echo Utils::$contador.PHP_EOL;
```

La información que se obtendrá en cada caso será:

```
0
1
6
15
```

Otro ejemplo muy común en el que sería justificado en este caso un método estático, sería que necesitaras en tu clase `Utils` un método para formatear contenido.

Esto es algo que yo uso en una aplicación en la que, por motivos que no vienen ahora al caso manejo cierta información guardada con símbolos que luego son sustituidos por otro tipo de contenido.

En la base de datos el contenido es más o menos fijo, pero ciertos símbolos se agregan según parámetros variables como el día de la semana, el mes en que estemos, etc.

En ese caso la clase `Utils` podría tener un método estático que llamaremos `formatText`, que recibirá el texto como esté construído y hará modificaciones en él cambiando los símbolos con un contrato pre-establecido.

```
public static function formatText($sTexto, $nTiempo=null) 
{

    $sTexto = str_replace("_", self::NBSP_SALMOS, $sTexto);
    $sTexto = str_replace("§", self::BRS, $sTexto);
    $sTexto = str_replace("~", self::BR, $sTexto);
    $sTexto = str_replace("¦", self::NBSP_4, $sTexto);
    $sTexto = str_replace("⊣", self::BR . self::NBSP_4, $sTexto);
    $sTexto = str_replace("≠", self::PRECES_R, $sTexto);
    $sTexto = str_replace("∞", self::PRECES_IL, $sTexto);
    $sTexto = str_replace("℟", '<font color="#d50000">℟.</font>', $sTexto);
    $sTexto = str_replace("℣", '<font color="#d50000">℣.</font>', $sTexto);
    return $sTexto;
}
```

El método es más largo y hace cosas más complejas con el parámetro `$nTiempo` cuando se requiere.

Otro método interesante y posible candidato a `static` sería un método donde muestras por ejemplo el Copyright o la licencia bajo el que compartes algún contenido.

```
public static function getCopyRight ($inicio) 
{
    $str='<div class="attribution"><a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/4.0/"></a><br />El contenido de este sitio está bajo una <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/4.0/">licencia de Creative Commons Reconocimiento-NoComercial 4.0 Internacional.</a><br>Significa que se podrá utilizar y compartir, sin fines comerciales.<br>Si aquí es compartido contenido bajo derechos de autor, y el mismo manifiesta su desacuerdo, dicho contenido será retirado.';

    $str.='<br>&copy '.$inicio.'-'.date("Y").' Nombre Autor | deiverbum.org<br /><br /><img alt="Licencia de Creative Commons" style="border-width:0" src="https://i.creativecommons.org/l/by-nc/4.0/88x31.png" /></div>';
    return $str;

}
```

Cabe decir que todo esto se declara dentro de la misma clase `Utils`, que, como su nombre lo indica, es una clase utilitaria que sirve de mucha ayuda en programas grandes para tener en un solo sitio cosas que repetimos muy a menudo. Además, esto da la posibilidad de cambiar en un solo sitio cualquier cosa que haya que actualizar.

---

### Otro aspecto muy importante: no confundir la utilidad de un miembro estático con una constante

Un error en el que se puede caer, sobre todo empezando, es en confundir `static` con `const`.  No es lo mismo. Una constante es un valor **que nunca va a cambiar**. Un ejemplo claro de constante sería el `PI`, que, hasta que no se pruebe la contrario, deberá valer siempre: `3.14`.

Para comprender mejor la diferencia, puedes leer [esta respuesta de Stackoverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1685933/5587982), si no la entiendes, puedes plantear tus dudas también aquí en la comunidad hispanohablante.

---

### Otras cosas a considerar

Hay que tener en cuenta lo que dice @Marcos en su comentario. Un *getter/setter*  no está justificado si `$valor` es declarado `public`, puesto que se podría obtener (get) y modificar (set) directamente, sin pasar por dichos métodos, como se ha mostrado más arriba.

Esto suele ocurrir cuando no entendemos del todo en qué casos usar una propiedad `static` y cuando no. Creo que con las explicaciones dadas queda más claro :)

---

> **NOTA SOBRE CONVENCIÓN DE NOMBRES:**
>
> Conviene que apliques una [convención de nombres](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/78517/29967) adecuada. Por ejemplo,
>   generalmente los nombres de clases deberían empezar por mayúsculas
>   todas sus palabras. Quizá tu clase debería llamarse: `WebSite`. Esto no es motivo de error, pero genera dificultades a la hora de analizar el código por otros programadores y por ti mismo en un futuro, en la medida en que el programa crece y vas incorporando nuevos elementos al mismo.

---

### Enlaces:

Para más detalles se pueden consultar los siguientes artículos:

- [Static methods and properties](https://phpenthusiast.com/object-oriented-php-tutorials/static-methods-and-properties)
- [Static Methods and Properties In PHP](https://www.johnmorrisonline.com/static-methods-properties-php/)
- [5 usages of static keyword in PHP](https://www.exakat.io/5-usages-of-static-keyword-in-php/)
- [PHP Static Methods and Static Properties](http://www.zentut.com/php-tutorial/php-static/)

Comment: Quizás valdría la pena señalar que `$valor` al ser una propiedad del tipo `public` se puede obtener el valor mediante `echo website::$valor` y establecer un valor con `website::$valor = 2;`. Quizás debería ser `private` y así justificar el uso de los métodos `get`  y `set`.

Comment: Estoy redactando algo mejor incluyendo lo que comentas @Marcos

Comment: Si es static, debería declararse ese valor en la misma definición, o en un constructor static. Esa propiedad es de 'clase', no de objeto, hay que dejar claro eso