# ¿Por qué obtengo error 500 al realizar un consulta con PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, debian, apache2

estoy realizando una consulta con PDO pero obtengo error 500, cuando realizo un SELECT. Lo estoy corriendo en un servidor Debian 9, PHP 7 y base de datos MariaDB en Google CLoud Server. La verdad me gustaria poder solucionarlo y no tener que reinstalar todo el servidor.

Tambien me ayudaria mucho si alguien me podria ayudar a reiniciar este error desde la consola y tambien cabe aclarar que PHPMyAdmin esta trabajando correctamente.

Revise las credenciales para la base de datos y estan correctas. En otro servidor similar a este habia probado el codigo que les expongo a continuacion y funciona correctamente.

```
<?php
    class Conexion
    {
        //VARIABLE PRIVADA
        private static $CONEXION;

        //FUNCION PARA LA CONEXION A LA DB
        private static function CONECTAR() 
        {
            //VARIABLES CON LOS DATOS PARA LA CONEXION
            $SERVER = 'localhost';
            $DATABASE = 'nombre_bd';
            $USUARIO = 'usuario_bd';
            $CONTRASENIA = 'Contraseña_bd';
            //$OPCIONES = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "set names utf8");
            //SE AGREGAR UN VALOR A LA CONEXION
            self::$CONEXION = null;
            //SE USA TRY POR ERRORES
            try
            {
                //SE EJECUTA LA CONEXION EN PDO
                self::$CONEXION = new PDO("mysql:host=".$SERVER."; dbname=".$DATABASE, $USUARIO, $CONTRASENIA, NULL);
                //
                self::$CONEXION->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            }
            catch(PDOException $EXCEPCION)
            {
                die($EXCEPCION->getMessage());
            }
        }

        //FUNCION PARA DESCONECTAR LA BASE
        private static function DESCONECTAR()
        {
            //SE CAMBIA EL VALOR DE LA VARIABLE PRIVADA
            self::$CONEXION = null;
        }

        //FUNCION PARA EJECUTAR CONSULTAS SQL RECIBIENDO EL VALOR Y LA CONSULTA
        public static function EJECUTAR_CONSULTA($CONSULTA, $VALOR)
        {
            try
            {
                //SE EJECUTA LA CONEXION A LA DB
                self::CONECTAR();
                //SE PREPARA LA CONSULTA A EJECUTAR
                $RESULTADO = self::$CONEXION->prepare($CONSULTA);
                //SE EJECUTA LA CONSULTA PASANDO EL VALOR
                $RESULTADO->execute($VALOR);
                //SE DESCONECTA LA DB
                self::DESCONECTAR();         
            }
            catch (Exception $EX)
            {   
                echo $RESULTADO -> errorCode();
            }
        }

        //FUNCION PARA LLAMAR UNA SOLA FILA RECIBIENDO EL VALOR Y LA CONSULTA
        public static function LLAMAR_FILA($CONSULTA, $VALOR)
        {
            //SE CONECTA LA DB
            self::CONECTAR();
            //SE PREPARA LA CONSULTA A EJECUTAR
            $RESULTADO = self::$CONEXION->prepare($CONSULTA);
            //SE EJECUTA LA CONSULTA PASANDO EL VALOR
            $RESULTADO->execute($VALOR);
            //SE DESCONECTA LA DB
            self::DESCONECTAR();
            //SE DEVUELVE LA FILA OBTENIDA EN UN ARREGLO
            return $RESULTADO->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
        }

        //FUNCION PARA LLAMAR MAS DE UNA FILA RECIBIENDO EL VALOR Y LA CONSULTA
        public static function LLAMAR_FILAS($CONSULTA, $VALOR)
        {
            //SE CONECTA LA DB
            self::CONECTAR();
            //SE PREPARA LA CONSULTA
            $RESULTADO = self::$CONEXION->prepare($CONSULTA);
            //SE EJECUTA LA CONSULTA PASANDO EL VALOR
            $RESULTADO->execute($VALOR);
            //SE DESCONECTA LA DB
            self::DESCONECTAR();
            //SE DEVUELVEN LAS FILAS OBTENIDAS EN UN ARREGLO
            return $RESULTADO->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
        }
    }

    $texto = Conexion::LLAMAR_FILAS("SELECT * FROM `ark_departamentos``",null);

?>
```

Comment: Tienes un backstick de más al final de la consulta: $texto = Conexion::LLAMAR_FILAS("SELECT * FROM `ark_departamentos``<-este sobra`",null); y en vez de `null` pásale un valor real o controla el método `LLAMAR_FILAS` para que cuando `$VALOR` sea `null` no use `prepare` ni `execute`, sino `query` simplemente. Tu código está planteado de forma incoherente en ese sentido, no deberías jamás pasarle `null` al `execute`
. Y la [*convención de nombres*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/78513/29967) que usas es horrible, las mayúsculas por lo general se usan sólo para constantes.