# Select en pdo con php

Tags: php, poo, select

buenas estoy empezando a hacer un mini proyecto utilizando php orientado a objetos el problema es que no me muestra un select y no se por que y no me da ningun error, como veréis en **productos.php** tengo comentado el execute, si lo descomento me dice que no reconoce la base de datos y la base de datos esta bien, es decir que no se el error, por mucho que intento cambiar cosas o no me muestra nada o me dice que hay base de datos o algo así
Mis archivos son:

**conexion.php**

```
class conexionBBDD{
private $servidor = "localhost";
private $BD = "tienda";
private $usuario = "root";
private $password = "";
private $conect;

public function conexion()
{
    $conectionString = "mysql:host = $this->servidor;dbname = $this->BD,charset=utf8";
    try {
        $this ->conect = new PDO($conectionString,$this->usuario,$this->password);
        $this->conect ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        // var_dump($this->conect);
        // print_r($conexion);
        // $this ->conect ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CASE,PDO::CASE_LOWER);
        // $this ->conect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE,PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        return $this->conect;
        // return $conexion;

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

}

**productos.php**

```
class productos extends conexionBBDD {
public $nombre;
public $cantidad;
public $precio;
public $id;

public function __construct($nom, $cant, $pre)
{
    $this->nombre = $nom;
    $this->cantidad = $cant;
    $this->precio = $pre;
}

public function selectProducto()
{
    $conexion = new conexionBBDD();
    $con = $conexion->conexion();

    $select = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM productos');
    // var_dump($select);

    // $select = $con->query("SELECT * FROM productos");
    // $select->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    // $select ->execute();

    if(!$select) {
        die("Error de consulta de ejecución, porque: ". print_r($con->errorInfo(),true) );
    }else {

        return $select;
    }
}

public function ningunDato() {
    return new self("","","");
}
```

}

**index.php**

```
  <?php
include "BBDD/productos.php";
$productos = productos::ningunDato();
$verProductos = $productos->selectProducto();

?>

<?php
    var_dump($verProductos);
while ($row = $verProductos->fetch()) {
?>
    <p><? echo $row["nombre"] ?> </p>
    <p>
        <? echo $row["precio"] ?>
    </p>
    <p>
        <? echo $row["cantidad"] ?>
    </p>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Por favor cambia las capturas de pantalla por el texto del código. Así es difícil analizar o reproducir el problema. Gracias.

Comment: @A.Cedano ya está perdona

Comment: Las consultas con PDO devuelven un recurso y necesitas que ese recurso esté activo (junto a la conexión) para leerlo. Me parece que al retornar el recurso desde la clase e intentar leerlo fuera de ella, la conexión (y en consecuencia el recurso) serían bulos en ese ámbito. Lo que debes hacer es leer el recurso en el método `selectProducto()` llenar un array por ejemplo y devolver ese array. Cuando el método hace `return` los recursos se cierran y no tienes contexto en el receptor para usar métodos como `fetch`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las consultas con PDO devuelven un recurso y necesitas que ese recurso esté activo (junto a la conexión) para leerlo. Me parece que al retornar el recurso desde la clase e intentar leerlo fuera de ella, la conexión (y en consecuencia el recurso) serían nulos en ese ámbito. Lo que debes hacer es leer el recurso en el método `selectProducto()` llenar un array por ejemplo y devolver ese array. Cuando el método hace `return` los recursos se cierran y no tienes contexto en el receptor para usar métodos como `fetch`.

Aparte de eso, si usas `prepare()`, es obligatorio usar `execute()`, aunque para este caso puedes usar `query()` porque no hay riesgo de inyección SQL.

Si lo haces así debería funcionar, salvo otros errores:

```
public function selectProducto()
{
    $conexion = new conexionBBDD();
    $con = $conexion->conexion();
    $select = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM productos');
    $select ->execute();
    $mData=array();
    if(!$select) {
        /* No conviene mostrar errores internos en producción*/
        $mData["error"]="Error de consulta de ejecución, porque: ". $con->errorInfo()[2];
    }else {
        while ($row = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
              $mData[] = $row;
        }
    }
    return $mData;
}
```

Como ves, los datos se leen en contexto en el que se obtienen. Luego, en el receptor, lees el array.

```
$allProducts = $productos->selectProducto();
foreach ($allProducts as $product){
    echo "$product[nombre] $product[precio] $product[cantidad]\n";
}
```

Tengo algunas críticas a tu forma de modelar las clases, pero ese es otro tema. Haciendo esto, debería funcionar, salvo otros errores en otras partes del código.

### Algunas recomendaciones

#### *Comprender y aplicar bien el concepto de herencia*

Una de las ventajas de la POO es que nos permite programar conforme a la realidad. Una norma muy simple es pensar los objetos como la realidad misma. En tu caso, al extender la clase productos de la conexión estás aplicando algo que se llama herencia de clases. Pero este concepto no existe para algo que *parece práctico*, pero que no lo es del todo. Parece muy bonito hacer extender tu clase de la clase conexión porque desde dentro de ella puedes conectar a la base de datos. Pero eso, desde el punto de vista de POO es un pésimo diseño.

El motivo es simple, una clase es una entidad, un tipo entendido como elemento filosófico (más bien metafísico). Desde ese punto de vista, un `Producto` como entidad no tiene nada que ver con una `Conexion`. Tomando un ejemplo más real para hablar de *herencia*, una clase `Pez` no debería extender (heredar) de la clase `Persona`. La `Persona` llamada `Juanito` no le deja la herencia al `Pez` llamado `Nemo`, porque no son entes que pueda heredar uno de otro. Una `Conexion` no debe dejarle su herencia a un `Producto`, son dos entes totalmente diversos.

Por eso la herencia, como decía al principio, no es para algo que parece práctico, es para aplicar algo así como una jerarquía de objetos que tienen propiedades en común (en su constitución metafísica). Un ejemplo de herencia sería una clase `Persona`, de ella pueden heredar clases como `Empleado`, `Vendedor`, `Atleta`, aquellas propiedades que son propias de las personas (nombre, sexo, fecha de nacimiento...). La herencia se crea pensando en esa jerarquía metafísica para poder reutilizar objetos y plasmar un modelo de datos que resuelve problemas muy complejos. Si por la misma regla metes a la conexión en este lío aquello que parecía tan bonito se convierte en una pesadilla.

Toda esta monserga es para decir que una conexión no debe extender nunca de clases como `Producto, Persona, Animal` etc. Ninguna persona nace con un conexión encima y la lleva siempre donde quiera que va. Cada vez que creas un producto, creas una instancia de la conexión, lo cual es absurdo.

Además, esa clase puedes necesitarla en un contexto donde la conexión no sea necesaria. Por ejemplo, un JSON que obtienes desde una API podría servirte para llenar tu clase, sin necesidad de conectar a la base de datos.

#### *Convención de nombre*

Es importante también aplicar una *Convención de nombre* estandarizada en POO. Por ejemplo, para clases, deben escribirse en singular y en PascalCase (cada primera letra en mayúscula), por ejemplo: `Producto`, `WordPress`, etc. Los métodos y otros componentes también tienen su convención de nombre ([ver aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/78517/29967)). Eso ayuda  comprender el código y a trabajar en equipo o proyectos grandes y a tenerlo organizado.

Comment: me gustaría saber que hago mal a la hora de modelar las clases? me gustaria aprender ya que estoy medio empezando ahora a hacer php orientado a objetos.

Comment: y respecto a la consulta me muestra esto y no se por que,: **Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected in C:\xampp\htdocs\TiendaPDO\BBDD\productos.php:27 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\TiendaPDO\BBDD\productos.php(27): PDOStatement->execute() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\TiendaPDO\index.php(15): productos->selectProducto() #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\TiendaPDO\BBDD\productos.php on line 27**

Comment: @SergioMartinez primero resolvamos el problema. Debes corregir la cadena de conexión, puede que sea la coma antes del charset, ponlo asi: `$conectionString = "mysql:host=$this->servidor;dbname=$this->BD;charset=utf8";` debe usarse punto y coma, y evita los espacios en blanco.

Comment: ya esta, tendria que ser que tuviera algun espacio en blanco o algo, muchas gracias

Comment: @SergioMartinez Sobre todo la coma aquí: `$this->BD,charset=utf8` debe usarse `;`, no `,`. ¿Ahora te muestra los datos?

Comment: si ya me lo muestra muchas gracias

Comment: ahora me gustaría saber lo eso de las clases, todo lo que pueda aprender mejor jaja

Comment: @SergioMartinez he puesto algunas recomendaciones al final de la respuesta.

Comment: vale ya lo he entendido mas o menos, que de la forma en la que estaba haciendo eso, al siempre estar iniciando una conexión es como darle mas trabajo al proyecto y poco eficiente por si decirlo

Comment: @SergioMartinez sí. Si piensas tus clases (aunque no todas deban ser así, porque puede haber clases utilitarias u otras) como entidades, eso te ayudará a no cometer errores de diseño por aparente facilidad que luego estropean el modelo. Además, PDO te permite por ejemplo mapear unos resultados en una clase. El mismo método `selectProducto()` es posible que deba estar en otra parte, fuera de la misma clase `Producto` en un modelo de datos más refinado.

Comment: El problema que ahora no se llamar a conexión si no es haciendo el extends, que me tengo que mirar para solucionar eso?

Comment: @SergioMartinez hay distintos paradigmas para organizar las clases, pero ese es un tema amplio que escapa al alcance de esta pregunta. Mis recomendaciones iban en el sentido de hacer ver que la POO es mucho más amplia. Hay paradigmas por ejemplo que hacen extender las clase de tipo entidad (`Persona, Producto`, etc) de otra clase que es la que se encarga de conectar, otro que usa DAO, etc.