# PHP &= y |=, una gran solución

Tags: php, validación, class, operador

Más que una pregunta es una explicación, en documentación he encontrado 0 datos y como me acaba de confirmar un colega [Daniel Gallego](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12467254/daniel-gallego) lleva más de 15 años activo.

La explicación es sencilla, imagínate que tienes una función que llama a un montón de funciones las cuales hacen x cosas, como por ejemplo instalar propiedades de un plugin, ¿como validas que todas hayan funcionado? ¿Haciendo un array de respuestas? ¿Haciendo un if true de la petición anterior?

Esto es una auto-Respuesta para que quede constancia de la información.

Salu2

Comment: Hola. En Stackoverflow puedes plantear una pregunta y autoresponder a ella. Es totalmente válido. En ese caso debes plantear la pregunta, dando fundamento a la misma y en seguida puedes autoresponder.

Comment: [Aquí hay un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/78513/29967) de pregunta con autorespuesta.

Comment: Buena idea, hecho y gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto Respuesta y Demostración del funcionamiento:

Validación siempre true:

```
public function valid(){
    $xxx = true;
    $xxx &= $this->x1();
    $xxx &= $this->x2();
    $xxx &= $this->x3();
    var_dump($xxx);
}
public function x1()
{
    return false;
}
public function x2()
{
    return true;
}
```

Devuelve int(0) lo que es lo mismo False, si alguna de las condiciones es false el cómputo global será False.

```
public function valid(){
    $xxx = false;
    $xxx |= $this->x1();
    $xxx |= $this->x2();
    var_dump($xxx);
}
public function x1()
{
    return true;
}
public function x2()
{
    return false;
}
```

Devuelve int(1) lo que es lo mismo True, si alguna de las condiciones es True el cómputo global será true.

Espero que se haya entendido y os sirva ya que después de 20 años programando me mola saber que no lo se todo.

Salu2