# Utilizar un método de una clase en otra POO PHP

Tags: php, poo

tengo una pequeña duda con poo en php y es que tengo 1 clase con un método repintar() (para que aplique un nuevo color a un coche) pero quiero utilizar ese método para otra clase vehiculo y no se como ponerlo, he probado algunas cosas pero no me sale.

```
       class vehiculo
   {
     private $color;
     private $peso;
    
     public function __construct($color, $peso)
     {
        $this->color=$color;
        $this->peso=$peso;
     }
   }

    class coche extends vehiculo
    {
        private $numero_puertas;
        
     public static function repintar($color)
     {
        $this->color = $color;
     }
   }
$vehiculo1= new Vehiculo("Verde", 1500);
$vehiculo1->repintar("Negro"); //error
```

Gracias.
Actualizado nombre de la clase.

Comment: porque si la funcion repintar es para todos los vehiculos, no esta en la clase padre?

Comment: Desde el punto de vista lógico, bastaría con un método `pintar()`, que serviría para pintar cualquier vehículo, el que sea viejo o nuevo nada tiene que ver con ese método, cuya función es *pintar*  cualquier vehículo, digo esto para arrojar un poco de luz en el diseño de tus clases, pues en POO ayuda mucho pensar las clases partiendo de la realidad. Otra cosa extraña es ver una clase llamada `cuatro_ruedas` ¿? La cantidad de ruedas que tenga un vehículo es una **propiedad** del mismo, ¿por qué usas una clase para definir una propiedad? Las clases suelen ser entidades, no propiedades.

Comment: Aclarado eso, el método `pintar()` bien podría estar en la clase `Vehiculo`  o no ... porque en un contexto amplio ese  método podría ser parte de otra entidad: `Taller`  por ejemplo, donde no solo se *pintan*, sino que también se *reparan*, *limpian*, *revisan* ... varios tipos de entidades, entre ellas `Vehiculo`.

Comment: cuatro_ruedas se refiere a vehículos de 4 ruedas igual que otra clase dos_ruedas para referir a motos. pintar() si podria estar en la clase padre pero precisamente esta ahí para aprender a como hacerlo desde otra clase.

Comment: La cantidad de ruedas es una **propiedad**, por lo tanto, no tiene sentido definirlo como una clase. Como ya dije, conviene pensar la POO partiendo de la realidad. ¡No existe ninguna entidad que sea solamente ruedas! ¿Acaso has visto cuatro ruedas o dos ruedas corriendo solas? No, la entidad es `Vehículo` y **tiene** ruedas. Si no entiendes ese concepto básico rápidamente estarás perdido en la POO. De hecho, parte de la confusión en tu pregunta es por no entender lo que trato de explicarte. Por otra parte, hay vehiculos de 3, de 8, de 10 ruedas. ¿Definirás una clase para cada uno?

Comment: Se lo que quieres decir, pero esta puesto en sentido cuatro_ruedas seria coche y dos_ruedas seria moto. He definido mal el nombre de la clase, pero entiendo lo que quieres decir. A.Cedano.

Comment: una clase padre, no puede llamar a un metodo de una clase hijo, simplemente porque la clase padre no sabe que tiene hijos. Entonces, no, no se puede...

Comment: Eso mismo estaba mirando en la documentación ahora mismo, gracias @gbianchi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varios conceptos que no están bien en el código. Los [métodos estáticos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.static.php#language.oop5.static.properties) no pueden acceder a los métodos ni atributos de instancia. Para acceder a atributos y métodos de instancia se requiere un objeto inicializado en esa clase. Lo ilustraré con un ejemplo:

```
<?php

class One {
    public $var1 = "Verde";
    public static $var2 = "Rojo";
}

class Two {
    static $var3 = "Azul";
    public $var4 = "Negro";
    public static function color1() {
        echo One::$var1;
    }
    public static function color2(){
        echo One::$var2;
    }
    public static function color3() {
        echo self::$var3;
    }
    public static function color4() {
        echo self::$var4;
    }
    public function color5() {
        echo $this->var4;
    }
}
```

Ahora haciendo algunas pruebas:

```
Two::color1(); // Error: Access to undeclared static property One::$var1
Two::color2(); // Rojo
Two::color3(); // Azul
Two::color4(); // Error: Access to undeclared static property Two::$var4
Two::color5(); // Error: Non-static method Two::color5() cannot be called statically

// Creando un objeto
$obj = new Two();
$obj->color5(); // Negro
```

Entonces, un método estático no puede cambiarle el color a tu Vehículo. Para ello tiene que ser un método de instancia.
Por otro lado, los atributos de la clase `vehiculo` no pueden ser ***private*** si van a ser heredados por otra clase, deben ser ***public*** o ***protected***. Ver [concepto de visibilidad](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.visibility.php). Si los declaras ***private***, la clase hija no tendrá acceso a ellos y el método `repintar()` creará un atributo `$this->color` nuevo para el objeto de la clase `coche` que nada tiene que ver con el de la clase `vehiculo`.

Entonces, una versión modificada de tu código que quede funcional sería:

```
<?php
class vehiculo {
    protected $color;
    protected $peso;
    
    public function __construct($color, $peso) {
        $this->color = $color;
        $this->peso = $peso;
    }
}

class coche extends vehiculo {
    function __construct(...$args) { // Constructor de clase hija
        parent::__construct(...$args); // inicializacion constructor padre
    }
    
    public function repintar($color) {
        $this->color = $color;
    }

    public function get_color() {
        return $this->color;
    }
}

$vehiculo1 = new coche("Verde", 1500);
echo "El coche ahora es " . $vehiculo1->get_color();
// El coche ahora es Verde
$vehiculo1->repintar("Negro");
echo "El coche ahora es " . $vehiculo1->get_color();
// El coche ahora es Negro
```

[*] Se necesita el método `get_color()` para poder devolver el atributo `$this->color` ya que está declarado como ***protected*** y no puede ser accedido desde fuera de la clase. Si se hubiese declarado como ***public***, el método no es necesario y se puede llamar el atributo directamente:

```
$vehiculo1->color;
```

Answer (score 2):

¿**Todos** los vehículos (Coches, Camiones, Motos, Bicicletas, Naves Espaciales... LOL) tienen que ser pintados, o dicho de otro modo, deben tener una propiedad `color`? Si la respuesta es sí, como parece evidente, entonces el método `pintar()` debería estar en la clase padre que es `Vehiculo`.

Veamos un ejemplo donde además incluimos un tipo de manejo con respecto al asunto de las `ruedas`, discutido en comentarios. Aclaro que es sólo un ejemplo sobre cómo podrías determinar si se está intentando crear un `Coche`. Deberás implementar en `setRuedas()` toda la lógica necesaria para determinar el tipo de vehículo, impidiendo que una `Moto` tenga 50 ruedas, que un `Camion`  tenga 1 rueda y cosas así. Digo esto sólo para ilustrar que era un camino equivocado crear clases del tipo `CuatroRuedas`, `DosRuedas`, o `NRuedas`. La cuestión de las ruedas es una propiedad y debe ser controlada/resuelta en un método, no creando clases.

El ejemplo muestra también cómo se pasan propiedades del hijo al padre y cómo desde el hijo podemos invocar métodos como `toString()` para obtener la parte de información correspondiente al padre (podrías también definir las propiedades como `protected` y usarlas desde el hijo).

Es un ejemplo muy básico donde faltarían los *setter* y *getter*. De hecho, un nombre de método más adecuado podría ser quizá `setColor()` (que vendría a ser lo mismo que *pintar*), pero respetando la *convención de nombre* habitual.

Estas son las clases:

#### `Vehiculo`

```
class Vehiculo
{
     private $color;
     private $peso;
     private $ruedas;

     public function __construct($color, $peso, $ruedas=null)
     {
        $this->color=$color;
        $this->peso=$peso;
        $this->setRuedas($ruedas);
     }
 
     public function setRuedas($ruedas) 
     {
         #Aquí controlas la cantidad de ruedas y la clase llamadora
         #Si la clase hija no es Coche y no tiene 4 ruedas no se asigna la propiedad
         #Es sólo un ejemplo a ampliar
           
         if ($ruedas==4 && get_called_class()=="Coche")
         {
               $this->ruedas=$ruedas;
         }
     }  
       
     public function pintar($color)
     {
        $this->color = $color;
     }
       
     public function toString()
     {
          return "Color: {$this->color}  \tPeso: {$this->peso}  \tRuedas: {$this->ruedas}";
     }          
       
}
```

#### `Coche`

```
 class Coche extends Vehiculo
 {
    private $puertas;
    
    public function __construct($color, $peso, $ruedas=null, $puertas)
    {
        #Pasamos al padre las propiedades comunes
        parent::__construct($color, $peso, $ruedas);
        
        #Asignamos las propiedades particulares de Coche
        $this->puertas=$puertas;
        
    }    

    public function toString()
    {
          return parent::toString() . " \tPuertas: {$this->puertas}";
    }                  
    
  }
```

Veamos varios ejemplos:

```
#Creamos un Vehículo
$mVehiculo= new Vehiculo("Verde", 1500);
echo $mVehiculo->toString().PHP_EOL;

#Lo pintamos
$mVehiculo->pintar("Negro");
echo $mVehiculo->toString().PHP_EOL;

#Creamos un Coche
$mCoche= new Coche("Rojo", 850, 4, 5);
echo $mCoche->toString().PHP_EOL;

#Lo pintamos. Aquí pintar() es un método de Vehiculo
$mCoche->pintar("Blanco");
echo $mCoche->toString().PHP_EOL;
```

**Salida:**

```
Color: Verde    Peso: 1500      Ruedas: 
Color: Negro    Peso: 1500      Ruedas: 
Color: Rojo     Peso: 850       Ruedas: 4   Puertas: 5
Color: Blanco   Peso: 850       Ruedas: 4   Puertas: 5
```

Con ese ejemplo básico podrás intentar construir una clase `Moto` por ejemplo, o una clase `NaveEspacial`, y  podrás *pintar* ambos objetos desde la clase `Vehiculo`.

Por cierto, he usado la [*convención de nombre*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/78513/29967) habitual para clases que es `PascalCase`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha quedado mucho mas claro todo! Lo implementaré y seguiré haciendo pruebas con tu explicación.