# Por qué Eclipse IDE 2022-12 me da este aviso sobre el nombre de la clase? [PHP]

Tags: php, eclipse, ide

En Eclipse IDE 2022-12 tengo la siguiente clase declarada en el archivo `cTable.php`:

```
class Table
{
    // código
}
```

y en el margen izquierdo donde marca los errores y advertencias veo el siguiente mensaje:

```
el nombre de la clase debe ser "cTable"
```

A qué se debe? Según tengo entendido no hay un estándar o convención claramente definidas para nombrar los archivos aunque he visto que gran parte (no sé si la mayoría) de los desarrolladores nombra sus archivos de clase algo así como `Class.Table.php` o `Table_Class.php` por mencionar un par de ejemplos.

Y ya que estamos, si alguien sabe si este comportamiento de Eclipse se puede modificar agradecería que me oriente en cómo hacerlo porque no tengo idea de cómo buscar una solución en internet.

Graceas!

Comment: En PHP sí hay varias *convenciones de nombre* como podrás ver en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/78517/29967) y **todas** indican que los nombres de clase se escriban en `PascalCase`. Eso no quiere decir que sea obligatorio, pero es importante hacerlo, para comprensión del código en entornos de colaboración, y eso implica no sólo trabajo en equipo. Este mismo sitio es un entorno de colaboración: si planteas una pregunta con código estandarizado es más fácil entender el problema y ayudarte. Creo que no es buena idea evitar que el IDE te advierta de malas prácticas.

Comment: En cuanto al nombre del archivo, la práctica habitual es llamarlo como se llama la clase, aunque tampoco es obligatorio, pero si usas herramientas como Autoloader y llamas a los archivos de modo diverso, vas a tener muchos problemas para que Autoloader trabaje adecuadamente. En resumen: las convenciones no son obligatorias, pero existen para ayudarte a ti y a otros, no hay motivos para prescindir de ellas.

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias por las respuestas y aclaraciones. He leído tu otra respuesta y es muy clara. Preguntaba porque sumado al aviso de Eclipse, puse un par de códigos en Code Review y si bien me remarcaron sobre los nombres, fue algo muy vago y al pasar, restándole importancia.

Answer (score 0):

Como dijo A. Cedano en los comentarios a la pregunta, [dejo un enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/78513/convenci%C3%B3n-de-nombres-en-php/78517#78517) a su respuesta, bien clara por cierto, sobre las convenciones de nombres.